# Domain events, как решить проблему?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ddd, clean-architecture

Использую MediatR, .net 7, EF.
Есть пользователь, у которого на данный момент есть 2 события: AccountPasswordChangedEvent, TokensWasRemovedEvent.
AccountPasswordChangedEvent вызывается в UpdateUserPasswordCommandHandler:

```
private readonly IAccountService accountService;
private readonly IDomainEventsService eventsService;

public UpdateUserPasswordCommandHandler(IAccountService accountService, IDomainEventsService eventsService)
{
    this.accountService = accountService;
    this.eventsService = eventsService;
}

public async Task<ServiceResult<ResetPasswordResponse>> Handle(UpdateUserPasswordCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var (userId, res) = await accountService.ResetPasswordAsync(request, false, cancellationToken);
    if (res.Succeeded)
    {
        await eventsService.PublishAsync(new AccountPasswordChanged(userId));
    }
    return new ServiceResult<ResetPasswordResponse>(res);
}
```

В свою очередь обработчик AccountPasswordChangedEvent удаляет все токены пользователя:

```
private readonly IAccountService accountService;

public AccountPasswordChangedHandler(IAccountService accountService)
{
    this.accountService = accountService;
}

public Task Handle(DomainEventNotification<AccountPasswordChangedEvent> notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return accountService.RemoveTokenAsync(new LogoutCommand
    {
        UserId = notification.DomainEvent.UserId,
        RemoveType = RemoveTokenType.All
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

TokensWasRemovedEvent вызывается в LogoutCommandHandler:

```cs
private readonly IAccountService accountService;
private readonly IDomainEventsService publisher;

public LogoutCommandHandler(IAccountService accountService, IDomainEventsService publisher)
{
    this.accountService = accountService;
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public async Task<ServiceResult<LogoutResponse>> Handle(LogoutCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await accountService.RemoveTokenAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    if (result.Length > 0)
    {
        await publisher.PublishAsync(new TokensWasRemovedEvent(result));
    }
    return new ServiceResult<LogoutResponse>(new LogoutResponse { Count = result.Length });
}
```

Где обработчик этого события удаляет все удаленные токены из кеша:

```cs
private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;

public TokenWasRemovedHandler(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
}

public Task Handle(DomainEventNotification<TokensWasRemovedEvent> notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    foreach (var item in notification.DomainEvent.Tokens)
    {
        memoryCache.Remove($"apitoken={item}");
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Вопрос такой: можно ли пробросить новое событие TokensWasRemovedEvent в обработчике события AccountPasswordChangedHandler? Правильно ли это будет (могут ли события порождать события? Я такого не видел нигде, а если быть точнее, то видел и там было сказано, что это плохо)?

```cs
private readonly IAccountService accountService;
private readonly IDomainEventsService publisher;

public AccountPasswordChangedHandler(IAccountService accountService, IDomainEventsService publisher)
{
    this.accountService = accountService;
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public async Task Handle(DomainEventNotification<AccountPasswordChangedEvent> notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tokens = await accountService.RemoveTokenAsync(new LogoutCommand
    {
        UserId = notification.DomainEvent.UserId,
        RemoveType = RemoveTokenType.All
    }, cancellationToken);
    if (tokens.Length > 0)
    {
        await publisher.PublishAsync(new TokensWasRemovedEvent(tokens));
    }
}
```

Сразу отвечаю на вопрос "Почему события добавляются не через DbContext & Entity?" - удаление токенов происходит через ExecuteDeleteAsync (.net 7), который не затрагивает SaveChangesAsync. Смена пароля происходит через UserManager из которого нужно сначала получить ответ, что пароль изменен успешно (может вернуть IdentityError[]).

Comment: _могут ли события порождать события?_ - Могут. Это нормально.

Comment: То есть, приведенный мной пример, как я вижу решение - нормальный?
Есть ли какие-то статьи на эту тему? Я ничего не смог найти, к сожалению, чтобы понять, правильно я делаю или нет

Comment: Что-то конкретное не могу предложить. Искать по терминам Event-based, Event-driven architecture.